# CSS Slide to new width

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let's say by using jQuery I can set the width of a DIV doing this:

```
$('#perc_in').width("14%");
```

then I make it do this:

```
$('#perc_in').width("57%");
```

Is there a way I can make it so instead of going from 14 to 57 I can make it **SLIDE** the progress bar from 14 to 57 percent? It's a simple div around another div with the percent being the progress (aka width).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to achieve that:

```
$('#perc_in').animate({'width': '57%'}, durationInMilliSeconds);
```

Comment: That's the basic idea (upvoted) but if you want to slide from left to right it's worth noting the div should be relative/absolute/floated left. Kind of like a progress bar feel. (For more information on this jquery function and easing visit: http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: OK Cool. Does this look good? $('#perc_in').animate({'width': result+'57%'}, 100);

Comment: result+'57%' - looks wrong to me. You'll want a number 1-100 with a percentage sign.. Maybe "result + '%'"?